# How to fix Runtime error while running model for ultralytic yolo?

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, yolov5

I want to produce the profiling for the YOLO and I am using [yolo.py](https://github.com/jaskiratsingh2000/yolov5/blob/master/models/yolo.py) of [ultralytics/yolov5](https://github.com/jaskiratsingh2000/yolov5) they have everything pre-build to run the profiling that is getting the latency for each layer.

So I ran the following commands to get the output:

```
import torch
import torchvision

device = torch.device("cuda:0")

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', force_reload=True)

img = torch.rand(8 if torch.cuda.is_available() else 1, 3, 320, 320).to(device) 
y = model(img, profile=True)
```

So when I run this I get the following runtime error with some output

```
time (ms)     GFLOPS     params  module
      1.25       1.44       3520  models.common.Focus
      0.66       1.90      18560  models.common.Conv
      1.72       1.93      18816  models.common.C3
      0.46       1.89      73984  models.common.Conv
      1.95       4.02     156928  models.common.C3
      0.33       1.89     295424  models.common.Conv
      1.31       4.00     625152  models.common.C3
      0.39       1.89    1180672  models.common.Conv
      0.68       1.05     656896  models.common.SPP
      0.69       1.89    1182720  models.common.C3
      0.20       0.21     131584  models.common.Conv
      0.05       0.00          0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample
      0.06       0.00          0  models.common.Concat
      0.70       2.32     361984  models.common.C3
      0.17       0.21      33024  models.common.Conv
      0.06       0.00          0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample
      0.10       0.00          0  models.common.Concat
      0.80       2.33      90880  models.common.C3
      0.27       0.95     147712  models.common.Conv
      0.03       0.00          0  models.common.Concat
      0.68       1.90     296448  models.common.C3
      0.26       0.94     590336  models.common.Conv
      0.03       0.00          0  models.common.Concat
      0.60       1.89    1182720  models.common.C3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f21874f58c27> in <module>()
      1 img = torch.rand(8 if torch.cuda.is_available() else 1, 3, 320, 320).to(device)
----> 2 y = model(img, profile=True)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     25         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     26             with self.__class__():
---> 27                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     28         return cast(F, decorate_context)
     29 

/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/common.py in forward(self, imgs, size, augment, profile)
    253         if isinstance(imgs, torch.Tensor):  # torch
    254             with amp.autocast(enabled=p.device.type != 'cpu'):
--> 255                 return self.model(imgs.to(p.device).type_as(p), augment, profile)  # inference
    256 
    257         # Pre-process

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/yolo.py in forward(self, x, augment, profile)
    122             return torch.cat(y, 1), None  # augmented inference, train
    123         else:
--> 124             return self.forward_once(x, profile)  # single-scale inference, train
    125 
    126     def forward_once(self, x, profile=False):

/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/yolo.py in forward_once(self, x, profile)
    134                 t = time_synchronized()
    135                 for _ in range(10):
--> 136                     _ = m(x)
    137                 dt.append((time_synchronized() - t) * 100)
    138                 if m == self.model[0]:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/yolo.py in forward(self, x)
     44         self.training |= self.export
     45         for i in range(self.nl):
---> 46             x[i] = self.m[i](x[i])  # conv
     47             bs, _, ny, nx = x[i].shape  # x(bs,255,20,20) to x(bs,3,20,20,85)
     48             x[i] = x[i].view(bs, self.na, self.no, ny, nx).permute(0, 1, 3, 4, 2).contiguous()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    397 
    398     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 399         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    400 
    401 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    394                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    395         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 396                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    397 
    398     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [255, 128, 1, 1], but got 5-dimensional input of size [8, 3, 40, 40, 85] instead
```

Can you let me know that how I can get this output without errors?
Output to be received:

```
 time (ms)     GFLOPS     params  module
      0.93       1.44       3520  models.common.Focus
      0.52       1.90      18560  models.common.Conv
      1.31       1.93      18816  models.common.C3
      0.38       1.89      73984  models.common.Conv
      1.58       4.02     156928  models.common.C3
      0.37       1.89     295424  models.common.Conv
      1.48       4.00     625152  models.common.C3
      0.51       1.89    1180672  models.common.Conv
      0.79       1.05     656896  models.common.SPP
      0.98       1.89    1182720  models.common.C3
      0.18       0.21     131584  models.common.Conv
      0.03       0.00          0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample
      0.05       0.00          0  models.common.Concat
      0.87       2.32     361984  models.common.C3
      0.16       0.21      33024  models.common.Conv
      0.05       0.00          0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample
      0.09       0.00          0  models.common.Concat
      0.81       2.33      90880  models.common.C3
      0.35       0.95     147712  models.common.Conv
      0.03       0.00          0  models.common.Concat
      0.80       1.90     296448  models.common.C3
      0.35       0.94     590336  models.common.Conv
      0.03       0.00          0  models.common.Concat
      1.04       1.89    1182720  models.common.C3
      0.69       1.47     229245  Detect
14.4 ms total
```

Comment: I found that you asked this on the yolov5 github. Did you try their recommendation of uncommenting https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/184991672636838453e796f72268833dff788d07/models/yolo.py#L41 ??

Comment: @jhso yes, here you can see my forked version in which I have changed that https://github.com/jaskiratsingh2000/yolov5/blob/master/models/yolo.py

Also here is link to my Google collab - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PRjPmQ8Nk7oM0KUcGfMBLVWSyNQ29lih?usp=sharing